# Networked-aframe: disabling look-controls also disables wasd-controls

Tags: aframe

When using **[networked-aframe](https://github.com/networked-aframe)**, disabling the `look-controls` component on the camera rig (`player.setAttribute("look-controls", { enabled: false });`) seems to disable the `wasd-controls` component on this same rig. **This issue does not occur when networked-aframe isn't used**. Please check out the glitch below (enabling/disabling look-controls happens on lines 58 onward).

Thanks!

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/naf-disable-look-controls - press **o** to disable look-controls & **p** to enable it.

Comment: Glitch link doesn’t seem to load

Comment: Fixed! Apologies.